# Uniqueness of the uniform distribution on hypersphere

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, harmonic-analysis

I'm looking for a uniqueness-type result for the following problem, which is related to the uniform distribution in the hypersphere $\mathbb{S}^{p-1}$. Suppose $f$ is a sufficiently smooth function on $\mathbb{S}^{p-1}$ such that $\int_{\mathbb{S}^{p-1}} f(x) dx=1$, $c_p = \mu(\mathbb{S}^{p-1})^{-1}$, and
$$\int_{\mathbb{S}^{p-1}} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{p-1}} g(x^{\top}y) f(x)f(y) dxdy = c^2_p \cdot \int_{\mathbb{S}^{p-1}} \int_{\mathbb{S}^{p-1}} g(x^{\top}y) dxdy,$$
for all bounded measurable functions $g: [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. I want to know whether this (possibly with extra assumptions) would imply $f \equiv c_p$? I appreciate any comments or reference.

Comment: Do you have a response to the answers below?

Comment: Thank you for the elegant proof!

Comment: I am glad you liked it. Just in case, here are possibly relevant here [MathOverflow guidelines](https://mathoverflow.net/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 8):

$\newcommand\S{\mathbb S}$The answer is yes, and it is enough to assume that $f$ is continuous.

It is convenient to renormalize the uniform distribution on the sphere so that it be the uniform *probability* distribution -- that is, so that $c_p=1$ and
\begin{equation*}
    L(g):=\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx \int_{\S^{p-1}} dy\, g(x^{\top}y) f(x)f(y) = 
    \int_{\S^{p-1}}dx \int_{\S^{p-1}} dy\,g(x^{\top}y)=:R(g) \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
for all bounded measurable functions $g\colon[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}$.

For $h\in(0,2]$, let
\begin{equation*}
    g_h:=\frac{1_{[1-h,1]}}{p_h}, 
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    p_h:=\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx \int_{\S^{p-1}} dy\,1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y)
    =\int_{\S^{p-1}} dy\,1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y)=:p_{h;x}     \tag{15}\label{15}
\end{equation*}
for any $x\in\S^{p-1}$, by the spherical symmetry.
Then
\begin{equation*}
\text{$R(g_h)=1$ for all $h\in(0,2]$.}  \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}

Next,
\begin{equation*}
L(g_2)=\Big(    \int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)\Big)^2. \tag{30}\label{30}
\end{equation*}
On the other hand,
\begin{equation*}
    L(g_h)\underset{h\downarrow0}\longrightarrow\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)^2; \tag{40}\label{40}
\end{equation*}
see details below, at the end of this answer.

So, in view of \eqref{10}, \eqref{20}, \eqref{30}, and \eqref{40},
\begin{equation*}
\Big(   \int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)\Big)^2=\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)^2=1.
\end{equation*}
Using now the equality condition in the Cauchy--Schwarz inequality and also the condition $\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)>0$, we see that $f=1$ almost everywhere. Since $f$ is continuous, we conclude that $f=1=c_p$. $\quad\Box$

**Details on \eqref{40}:** Note that for any unit vectors $x$ and $y$ we have $1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y)=1(|x-y|^2\le2h)$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm. Therefore and because $f$ is continuous, and hence uniformly continuous and bounded on $\S^{p-1}$, we have
\begin{equation}
    1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y)f(x)f(y)=1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y) (f(x)^2+o(1))\text{ as }h\downarrow0 
\end{equation}
uniformly in all unit vectors $x$ and $y$. Therefore and in view of \eqref{15}, for $h\downarrow0$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    L(g_h)&=\frac1{p_h}\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx \int_{\S^{p-1}} dy\,1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y)f(x)f(y) \\ 
    &=\frac1{p_h}\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx \int_{\S^{p-1}} dy\,1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y)(f(x)^2+o(1))   \\ 
    &=\frac1{p_h}\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx \int_{\S^{p-1}} dy\,1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y)f(x)^2+o(1) \\ 
    &=\frac1{p_h}\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)^2\int_{\S^{p-1}} dy\,1_{[1-h,1]}(x^\top y)+o(1)   \\ 
    &=\frac1{p_h}\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)^2p_{h;x}+o(1) \\ 
    &=\frac1{p_h}\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)^2p_h+o(1) \\ 
    &=\int_{\S^{p-1}}dx\, f(x)^2+o(1),  
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
so that \eqref{40} follows.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative approach (in addition to the great answer by Iosif Pinelis), assuming only that $f \in L_2(\mathbb{S}^{d-1})$ --- since the post is tagged *harmonic analysis*, this idea might also be interesting. As in the Iosif's answer, we will normalize the uniform measure on the sphere to be probability distribution, and we will write $\mathbb{E}[\cdot]$ for integrals (or double integrals) with respect to this measure.

In this notation, the assumption states that for every (bounded, measurable) $g$, we have

$$\mathbb{E} [g(\langle x, y\rangle) f(x) f(y) ] = \mathbb{E}[ g(\langle x,y \rangle)].$$

Let's take $r := f - 1$, so that $\mathbb{E}[ r(x)] = 0$,
we have
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E} [g(\langle x, y \rangle) f(x) f(y)] & = \mathbb{E} [g(\langle z,y \rangle)] + 2 \mathbb{E} [g(\langle x,y \rangle) r(x)] + \mathbb{E} [g(\langle x,y \rangle) r(x) r(y)] \\
    &= \mathbb{E} [g(\langle x,y \rangle)]  + \mathbb{E} [g(\langle x,y \rangle) r(x) r(y)]
\end{align*}
since $\mathbb{E}_y[ g(\langle  x, y\rangle)]$ does not depend on $x$ and $\mathbb{E}[ r(x)] = 0$. The assunption then translates to
$$\mathbb{E} [g(\langle x,y \rangle) r(x) r(y)] = 0$$
for each $g$.

Let us now use $g(\langle x,y \rangle) = \langle x,y \rangle^k$ as a test function. We can write
$$\langle x,y \rangle^k = \sum_{|\alpha|=k} c_\alpha x^\alpha y^\alpha,$$
where $\alpha$ is an multi-index, and all coefficients $c_\alpha$ are positive. Hence
\begin{align*}
    0 &= \mathbb{E} [\langle x,y \rangle^k r(x) r(y)] = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha \mathbb{E} [x^\alpha y^\alpha r(x) r(y)] \\
 & = \sum_\alpha c_\alpha \mathbb{E}[x^\alpha r(x)]^2.
\end{align*}
hence $r$ has zero corelation with any monomial $x^\alpha$ on a sphere --- by linearity it has zero correlation with any polynomial, and since spherical harmonics form a complete basis for $L_2(\mathbb{S}^d),$ we must have $r = 0$.